# Is a library compiled every time a program invokes it?

Tags: c, compilation

From my understanding, a library is like an API for other programs to use. Since a library is not program, which is compiled and run forever unless you exit it, will the library be compiled every time a program invokes it? For example, if I want to call a get function in the library code, will the needed files be compiled again every time I call the function?

Comment: No, you are linking to the library, which is already the output of the compilation of the library's source files.

Comment: This is really a basic computer science question. You can find an answer in any textbook and gigabytes of Internet pages.

Comment: I cannot see that the votes to close as “unclear what you’re asking” are justified. The question is perfectly clear.

Comment: Kind of agree with @EricPostpischil - the OP might be unclear about the difference between compiling and dynamic linking - but the question itself is fine. Presumably, every question on SO could be answered with enough 'textbooks' or 'google searching' ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libraries for use in compiled languages are compiled at least to object modules and sometimes further, to dynamic libraries.

Typical steps in compiling a program are:

- For each source module, the source is compiled to produce an object module.
- One or more object modules are linked to produce an executable.
- An executable is loaded into memory and executed.

You might not see all of these steps in separate commands because the command(s) you use may be able to perform multiple steps.

Object modules may exist in individual files or may be collected into a library or archive file that contains any number of object modules.

If a library consists of object modules that are linked into an executable, it is called a static library. The object modules in this sort of library are essentially just like object modules built from the regular sources of your program. To make a library of this sort, you perform these steps:

- Compile the source modules for the library into object modules.
- Run a program such as `ar` to combine the object modules into an archive.
- Publish the archive so other people can use it.
- Document the library interfaces. (This step is too often neglected.)

In some operating systems, object modules may be linked into dynamic libraries instead of executables. Actually, executables, dynamic libraries, and object modules are similar in several ways: They contain segments with computer instructions, segments with data, and various instructions about how the segments should be loaded into memory and what symbols are defined or are needed by the executable, library, or module. One of the differences between them is the extent to which those symbol definitions and needs are resolved.

A dynamic library can be linked into your program while the program is executing. A program that uses dynamic libraries does not have all of its references fully resolved, even when it is loaded and starts execution: It has references to things in a dynamic library. When the program wants to use things from a dynamic library, it executes code that finds the file containing the dynamic library (which is fully compiled and partially linked) and that loads that library into memory and resolves references to the library.

Answer (score -2):

no
.........................................

a library is not recompiled every time you call it

Comment: Please write a bit more...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.